# How to split a full=number into two groups according to their position(even or odd)

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I need to split a txt file into 2 arrays
The txt file contains full number.Can I do it without string?
For example,for input

```
4(how many line)
2 1
3 7
8 0
3 7
```

I want array 1 contains (firt number in a line)

```
{2 
3 
8 
3}
```

array 2 contains (second number in a line)

```
{1 
 7
 0 
 7}
```

How can I do that?Just curious...Here is a code which does not work..

```
ifstream ifs("sth.txt");
int g;
ifs>>g;
int girl[g];
int boy[g];
for(int i=0;i<2*g,i++;){
if (i%2==0)ifs>>gil[g];
if (i%2==1)ifs>>boy[g];}
cout<<boy[1];
```

Comment: Your array declarations are not valid C++ (yet); they are a GCC-specific extension. Use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
ifstream ifs("sth.txt");
int g;
ifs>>g;
int girl[g];
int boy[g];
for(int i=0;i<g,i++;){
    ifs>>girl[i];
    ifs>>boy[i];
}
cout<<boy[0];
```

You were reading to `girl[g]` and `boy[g]` instead of `0..(g-1)`.

I also changed reading: two ints insted of 1 in one iteration of the loop.

At the end I changed counting first (index 0) instead of second element of `boy`.

Comment: Sure, but just compare how much simpler Ari's code is than yours. No ifs with modulo inside. You have g lines of numbers, each containing two numbers that you treat differently. It makes much more sense to make the loop iterate once per line and do the two different things one after the other than make the loop iterate once per number and decide in each iteration what to do.

Comment: @user2604063 yes we g times reading two numbers, so we are reading 2g numbers.

Answer (score -1):

```
ifstream ifs("sth.txt"); 
int g;
ifs>>g;
int girl[g];
int boy[g];
for(int i=0;i<g,i++;){
    ifs>>gil[i];
    ifs>>boy[i];
}
cout<<boy[0];
```

or

```
int a =0; b = 0;
for(int i=0;i<g;i++){
     if(i%2) ifs>>boy[b++];
     else ifs>>girl[a++];
}
```

or

```
for(int i=1;i<=g;i+=2){
    ifs>>boy[(i-1)/2];
    if(i+1<=g)
        ifs>>girl[(i-1)/2];
}
```

or

```
std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
for(int i=0;i<g;i++){
  fscanf(str,"%d %d",boy[i],girl[i]);
}
```

Comment: you are reading first g/2 numbers to `girl` and then second g/2 numbers to `boy`. It can't work that way. You need to read one number to girl, one to boy and so on.

Comment: Actually I use the first one

Comment: Sure u use the first one. But how about doing it on your own and if not, how about accepting the other dudes answer ??