# How to split a full=number into two groups according to their position(even or odd)

Tags: c++, arrays

My input is like

```
 4
 1 2
 3 4
 5 6
 7 8
```

What I want to do is to split it into 2 groups.
[How to split a full=number into two groups according to their position(even or odd)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856976/how-to-split-a-full-number-into-two-groups-according-to-their-positioneven-or-o)
I asked it here.Ithought the answer is correct.When I check it with boy[3];
there seems to be some problem.Here is the code,I cannot find the mistake?What should be out is 8

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
ifstream ifs("Q3_IN.txt"); 
int g;
ifs>>g;
int boy[g];int girl[g];
int a =0; int b = 0;
 for(int i=0;i<g;i++){
 if(i%2) ifs>>boy[b++];
 else ifs>>girl[a++];
 }
 cout<<boy[3];
 system("pause");
 return 0;}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly and use spaces consistently around operators.

Answer (score 1):

`i < g*2` is your solution. Your input size is 2*g but not g.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you don't need to make it so complicated. There are always two numbers on a line, so

```
 for(int i=0;i<g;i++){
 if(i%2) ifs>>boy[b++];
 else ifs>>girl[a++];
 }
```

can be done as:

```
 for(int i=0;i<g;i++){
    ifs>>girl[i] >>boy[i];
 }
```

No need to check if it's even or odd, because you simply need to store each girl then boy.